# 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.INotifyPropertyChanged' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am on windows 8 Pro RTM 64 bit machine with VS 2012. I am building a simple metro application. I have a class with no code in it yet and trying to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface. However, I get the error

> 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.INotifyPropertyChanged' is inaccessible due to
>   its protection level.

I know it is a known bug and been fixed. However, On my machine i still get it. Is there any update i need to install?

PS : There is an INotifyPropertyChanged in System.ComponentModel but it is of no use here.

Answer (score 0):

This is confusing because of the aging information that's out there on various blogs, forums, etc.

There was indeed an issue; however, the API projections have been resolved, and the resolution is that `System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged` *is* the correct interface to use.

The [documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh758320.aspx) reflects this as well (scroll about a third of the way down to the table showing data binding scenarios.

Comment: oh..I was under impression that we need to use 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Data' namespace. i will test my sample code and will mark this post as answer.